# Swift - What is the best approach for remove hardcoded string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, dictionary

Dictionary key showing as hardcoded string so searched a best way to remove it.

```
let sentObj : [String:Any] = [
    "id": Int(objData["_id"] as! String)!,
    "boolPresentValue": "234",
    "compositePropertiesString":objData["compositePropertiesString"]!
]
```

Comment: which string yoou want to remove ?

Comment: ... The keys to your `sentObj` dictionary? The keys within `objData`? The `"234" `?

Comment: @Jok3r dictionary showing like a string. I want replace to a proper code.

Comment: @Jok3r I know three way to fix. 1- getter method , 2 - struct  3 - enum. please tell me what's the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we use is creating a private struct keep all the string literals and use it.

Something like

```swift
private struct ViewControllerCosntants {
    static let category = "Category"
    static let rating = "Rating"
    static let currentNav = "Current Nav"
    static let type = "Type"
}
```

And use it like

```swift
ViewControllerCosntants.category
```

Where ever I needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: willRemoveKey)
```

try this

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.